# Related on Class Library Dll code to appear on sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I created a class library project with Adding webusercontrols in it,after building the solution i copy the dll in bin folder of sharepoint site..and also wrote the safecontrolsassembly in the web.config file...doing all these things successfully iam not getting reflected the dll in my sharepoint site..
  Can tell why this happens?

Thanks in Advance,
Naresh

Comment: Can you tell us how is not getting reflected ?

Comment: yeah..i added in dll in bin and also mention safecontrolassembly..and also usercontrol in controltemplates folder..so after all this if i opens the site it should get some changes which i made through code..but its not getting

Comment: where did you add the control to, application page? any error messages?

Comment: Application page..dll in virtualdirectories\999\bin